# Button click not firing anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a website, and within it there are a few buttons. These stopped working in the last day or two for some reason that I cannot figure out.

Here is the Click function.

```
    //Click "Belgium"
    $('#actions').on('click', '#btnBelgium', function ()
    {
        console.log("belgium pressed");
        clearTableRows();
        irelandMatches.length = 0;
        nation = "belgium";
        loadDoc();
        document.getElementById("btnSort").value = "Sort: Descending";
        matchOrderReversed = false;
    });
```

This is the HTML:

```
    <div id="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="Sort: Descending" id="btnSort">

        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnBelgium">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnIreland">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnItaly">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnSweden">
    </div>
```

The entire section page of Javascript is contained within:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you added some other click event with stopPropagation?

Comment: I [made a js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3twL037/) and the click event seems to be working fine but I did get a "clearTableRows is not defined" js error in the console.

Comment: Problem solved. I had a method which wasn't working being called, however, it had nothing to do with the click or this div/buttons/etc. Thanks for the help guys. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece of code you provided works. Button click if firing. Check if you have any errors in js console in dev tools. There should be some other problem.

```js
    //Click "Belgium"
    $('#actions').on('click', '#btnBelgium', function ()
    {
        console.log("belgium pressed");
        alert('clicked');
        clearTableRows();
        irelandMatches.length = 0;
        nation = "belgium";
        loadDoc();
        document.getElementById("btnSort").value = "Sort: Descending";
        matchOrderReversed = false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="Sort: Descending" id="btnSort">

        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnBelgium">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnIreland">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnItaly">
        <input type="submit" class="navButton" value="" id="btnSweden">
    </div>
```

Comment: Didn't solve my problem as it was some other factor that caused it, but this works, and provides a sample of the code running.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use?

```
$('#btnBelgium').bind('click', function ()
{
    console.log("belgium pressed");
    clearTableRows();
    irelandMatches.length = 0;
    nation = "belgium";
    loadDoc();
    document.getElementById("btnSort").value = "Sort: Descending";
    matchOrderReversed = false;
});
```

Comment: because the buttons might be getting added later in action buttons

Comment: But he gave the template and button already was there

Comment: might be so we can understand better. Hey I am keeping an open mind

Comment: Use `on` instead of `bind`, as `bind` is a candidate for deprecation. `on` is the new way. Internally to jQuery `bind` maps to `on`.